# How can I use the new FormData methods apart from append?

Tags: javascript, form-data

Right now I'm trying to use the `FormData.getAll` method which is specified here: 
[FormData from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Methods). I'm using Chrome *Version 42.0.2311.90* and the MDN says that is compatible: [image]

But when I crate a `FormData` object it only has the `append` method:

[image]

So, is this not released yet? if so, when will we have access to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDN's compat table is wrong; I'll make sure it gets updated.

As of Chrome 44.0.2376.0 dev, these methods are only available behind the "Enable Experimental Web Platform Features" flag.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Do you know if there are any plans for making those methods available without the  "Enable Experimental Web Platform Features" flag ?

Comment: for future dev coming here, this is the flag url: chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features